# How do I embed the share in another website?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have a website in which I would like to embed the share using an iframe. The problem is how do prevent the user having to login (in the iframe). They are already authenticated at this point.

The parent application which is generating the iframe is on the same server/domain as the Alfresco install.

The parent application has its own authentication, but instead of storing its own passwords it queries Alfresco via REST.

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. But I think you are asking once you are logged in what can you do to prevent logging in again. If that's the case then when you log in Alfresco will give you an authentication token name alf_ticket. For any following request you can use that token added to the request parameters. You could then maybe set up your iframe to some URL with that token added. Maybe that would work. Not sure though... :)

Comment: Logging in with a ticket would be perfect. I already have the ticket since our regular login delegates to Alfresco. Any ideas how I pass the ticket in the URL to log in to share?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways, i think:

- The first is to provide token (you shoud have one in your parent app) to Share in iFrame, so use some javascript;
- The second one is to use portlets, have a look for example at [liferay wiki](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Alfresco+integration), at least document library [should](http://alfrescoshare.wordpress.com/2010/06/11/alfresco-share-repository-integrated-into-a-portal-liferay/) be accessible.

Comment: I think an iframe would be best since the parent app is not written in Java.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using php, (Wordpress, joomla, etc) then this can be useful. 
First of all you need to configure the share-security-config to allow put share content into an iframe [configure iframe](https://www.alfresco.com/blogs/ewinlof/2013/03/12/introducing-the-securityheaderspolicy-in-alfresco-share/).

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="SecurityHeadersPolicy">
  <headers>         
     <header>
        <name>X-Frame-Options</name>
        <value>ALLOW-FROM https://www.x.com</value>
        <!--or just allow all-->
        <!--<enabled>false</enabled>-->
     </header>
```

Then [Configuring external authentication](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/auth-external-intro.html) and last pass the header using that [Configuring Alfresco Share to use an external SSO](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/auth-alfrescoexternal-sso.html).